# Getting error when adding OSSubprocess to my Pharo 6.1 on Centos 7.4x

Tags: smalltalk, gnutls, libssl, pharo-6

I wanted to mess around with [`OSSubprocess`](https://github.com/pharo-contributions/OSSubprocess#installation) (written by [Mariano Martinez Peck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279340/mariano-martinez-peck)) from my Pharo 6.1 on my CentOS 7.4.

I searched within the `Pharo Project Catalog` and tried to install it.

I got an error:

```
ioLoadModule(/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836/libgit2.so):
  libcurl-gnutls.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
tryLoading(/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836/libgit2.so/.libs/,libgit2.so): stat(/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836/libgit2.so/.libs/) Not a directory
ioLoadModule(/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836/libgit2.so):
  libcurl-gnutls.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
tryLoading(/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836/libgit2.so/.libs/,libgit2.so): stat(/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836/libgit2.so/.libs/) Not a directory
```

Apparently, some libraries as `libcurl-gnutls` are needed by the `libgit2.so`.

```
ls -la | grep git
-rw-r--r--. 1 smalltalk smalltalk 3019447 May  9 08:55 libgit2.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 smalltalk smalltalk 3019447 May  9 08:55 libgit2.so.0.25.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 smalltalk smalltalk 3019447 May  9 08:55 libgit2.so.25
[smalltalk@smalltalk 5.0-201805090836]$ pwd
/home/smalltalk/App/pharo6.1-64/pharo-vm/lib/pharo/5.0-201805090836
```

When I check the dependencies with `ldd libgit2.so`:

```
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./libgit2.so'
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcd7aea000)
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => not found
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f09ff332000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libssh2.so.1 => /lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007f09ff107000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f09feeff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f09fece3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f09fe91f000)
    libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f09fe6ad000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f09fe24c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056133cf8c000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f09fdffe000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f09fdd16000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f09fdb12000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f09fd8de000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f09fd6da000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f09fd4cc000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f09fd2c7000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f09fd0ad000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f09fce85000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f09fcc23000)
```

The issue is apparently with:

```
    libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => not found
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

`libcurl-gnutls.so.4` library is not [apparently](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64227) shipped with CentOS 7 at all:

> We just don't supply anything called libcurl-gnutls* at all. Our curl doesn't use gnutls.

`libssl.so.1.0.0` is ancient (same goes for `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`). If I check my `libssl`:

```
sudo ls -l /usr/lib64/libssl*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 341024 May 16 17:20 /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Jan 31 13:40 /usr/lib64/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.2k
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Jan 31 13:34 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.2k
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 470336 Aug  4  2017 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k

sudo ls -l /usr/lib64/libcrypto*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 Jan 31 13:40 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      19 Jan 31 13:34 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2512448 Aug  4  2017 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
```

The CentOS 7 details are:

```
   Static hostname: smalltalk
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: beb4030b979d4cdcbf51ec99034121fc
           Boot ID: 02ef7d00b2e74489bdb78dead7e2fcf8
    Virtualization: kvm   Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

### Now the million dollar question:

How do you deal with such a situation?  Is there a reasonable way to recompile the whole `Pharo VM` or just the [`libgit2`](https://theseion.github.io/libgit2-pharo-bindings/) library against the newer libraries' versions?

Comment: Did anyone played with it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems related to a question asked here: http://forum.world.st/Pharo-download-with-wget-td5099253.html

The suggested solution in the thread and the one that also works for me is to created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib64/libcurl-gnutls.so.4
```

Comment: I'll try it out when I get back to it.