# Pharo on RaspberryPi: Module not found at startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian, smalltalk, pharo

I am on a raspbian stretch system with the spur32 VM for ARM and a Pharo 7 image. At Startup I always get an `exception: Error - Module not found`.

It seems to have to do with `lgitlibrary`. I really cannot figure out what this error is about.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
Henrik

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it has to do something with `lgitlibrary`?  The error is rather generic.

Comment: Just because a LGitLibrary throws the exception. Of course I am not sure - but it seems that way.

Comment: Could you do a screenshot of the exception window?

Comment: Done. See original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see.  If you check `#unixModuleName`

```
unixModuleName
    | pluginDir |
    pluginDir := Smalltalk vm binary parent.
    #('libgit2.so' 'libgit2.so.0')
        detect: [ :each | (pluginDir / each) exists ] 
        ifFound: [ :libName | ^ libName ].

    self error: 'Module not found.'
```

Here you have your error message: `self error: 'Module not found.'`

You probably have `libgit2.so` or `libgit2.so.0` missing (or dependencies).  You may suffer with similar problem as me: [Getting error when adding OSSubprocess to my Pharo 6.1 on Centos 7.4x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399321/getting-error-when-adding-ossubprocess-to-my-pharo-6-1-on-centos-7-4x).

You should check the dependencies with `ldd` (check my question for details).

**Edit** Adding information due to comment:

I have yet to use IceBerg (the Pharo's git integration).  My guess, would be to *"(re-)initialize it"*: `(Smalltalk at: #LGitLibrary) initialize.`

For more information, I recommend reading these: [pharo's iceberg](https://github.com/pharo-vcs/iceberg) and some Pharo project that uses git like [pharo-contributor](https://github.com/astares/pharo-contributor) and checking blog pharoweekly (for some information about the pharo-contributor) - https://pharoweekly.wordpress.com/2018/04/24/pharo-contributor-to-contribute-to-pharo.

You may want to use some guide [*"How to use git and github with Pharo"*](https://www.peteruhnak.com/blog/2016/07/25/how-to-use-git-and-github-with-pharo/).  Which was done by [Peter Uhnak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007760/peter-uhnak) (you can find him on SO).

Comment: Thanks. I do have libgit2.so including all dependencies. I don't have libgit2.so.0 - but one of them should be enough, right?

Comment: Yes, one is enough. #detect:ifFound: will trigger upon at least one detected and return ^ llibName. Are you sure you have at least one? (In the `pluginDir` not in the system!) You could see if Pharo see it by replacing ifFound: [ :libName | Transcript show: libName ]. Second question is if the libgit2.so is compatible with your ARM system. Third are the dependencies in the correct versions?

Comment: Okay, thanks so much! I had the file in the system, but not in my actual pluginDir. So that hint did the trick. I just put a symlink into the pluginDir. Only one last question: Do you happen to know how I can check whether this actually works and is not just satisfying the file being there?

Comment: @HenrikGuschov I have added more information about Pharo's git.  For more I recommend opeining separate question.  It makes life easier for those that are searching for answers to their questions.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and I needed to build libgit2 library from source using this [instructions](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=pharo%20libgit&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). The basic build didn't work because Pharo wasn't able to initialize the library. I compiled it again with parameter -DSTDCALL=ON an it works.