# How do I get a Twitter feed using Pharo?

Tags: ssl, twitter, uri, smalltalk, pharo

Since Twitter changed their website design, I cannot get a set of tweets from any account by using built-in Zinc classes. It throws an error that says: `ConnectionClosed: Connection closed while waiting for data`

I am using **Pharo 5**, and I don't know how to tweak the ZnClient settings in order to keep the connection open or something to the purpose of getting the data.

```
testTwitter
    | client |
    self ensureSocketStreamFactory.
    self isNativeSSLPluginPresent ifFalse: [ ^ self ]. 
    (client := ZnClient new) 
        get: 'https://www.twitter.com/pharoproject'.
    self assert: client isSuccess.
    self assert: (client contents includesSubstring: 'Twitter').
    client close
```

That's the test I have in place, it never passes, and throws the error mentioned above. What's missing here? I did a Ruby script using open-uri, openssl and Nokogiri and it fetched the tweets just fine. Perhaps it's a problem with the SSL connection itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is quite easy to answer, but you won't like it.  Your issue is connected to the fact that the [Twitter has deprecated support for TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 on July 15/2019](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/twitter-will-deprecate-support-for-tls-1-0-tls-1-1-on-july-15/).  Your pharo is using the deprecated TLS to connect. That is the reason why you are getting the timeout.

### The solution?

You have to compile the new SSL/TLS support yourself which is not an easy task to do.  You have to compile in **at least TLS 1.2** to be able to connect again.  There is lack of Pharo documentation how to compile support for new libraries.  My guess is that you are using TLS 1.0 (see a note below) - since Pharo 6.1 (so your Pharo 5.x will have same or older libraries) has `libgit2.so` compiled against `libssl.so.1.0.0` (which has dependency `libcurl-gnutls.so.4`) - If you update the libraries you can [see](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-compared.html) that those support >= TLS 1.2.

### Note:

This is connected to the issue which I have posted some time ago.  Nobody upvoted it or answered so it got automatically deleted - you can vote to undelete it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399321/getting-error-when-adding-ossubprocess-to-my-pharo-6-1-on-centos-7-4x (see the bottom of the post for the question).  I don't have an answer for that as I have dedicated time to my Smalltalk/X project.

Answer (score 2):

Or just switch to a newer Pharo. Adding your method to `ZnHTTPSTest` in **Pharo 8** just works (tested on **Pharo 8 build 686**, Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS with the stable vm in `PharoLauncher`)

Comment: That is true, but the question is why you would have to change Pharo version when you have your code working and deployed.  It would be much easier to have a documented way to recompile new libraries against any Pharo version.